# Why I can't get my data on the client? Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

Client code:

```
fetch(`${this.url}?url=${this.getInputData()}`)
      .then(res => {
        return JSON.parse(res);
      })
      .then(data => {
        const renderer = new GalleryRenderer();
        renderer.renderImages(data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Express code:

```
router.get("/url-parse", (req, res) => {
  const { query } = req;

  const { error } = Joi.object({
    url: Joi.string().required().uri(),
  }).validate(query);

  if (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  }

  parser
    .parse(query.url)
    .then(elemHandles => {
      return Promise.all(
        elemHandles.map(elemHanle => elemHanle.getAttribute("src")),
      );
    })
    .then(imgSources => {
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(imgSources));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw new Error(err);
    });
});
```

`JSON.stringify` stringifies an array of strings.

Such response I have on the client:

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/url-parse?url=some-url-here", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/url-parse?url=some-url-here"
```

And an error right below:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

As I understand, that error shows, that I have not received json data from the server.
Does anybody know what the reason? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change too

**ensures the response will have utf8 charset and application/json content-type**

```
.then(imgSources => {
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(imgSources));
 })
```

to

```
.then(imgSources => {
      res.status(200).json({imgSources});
 })
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the client script.
Instead of

```
.then(res => {
  return JSON.parse(res);
})
```

must be

```
.then(res => res.json())
```